# Organise android projects in eclipse and remove closed projects

Tags: eclipse

I want to know if there is anyway to organize the projects in Eclipse (In the package explorer) and remove closed ones.

Comment: r u want to remove it from harddisk or workspace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the project, then don't select 'delete from harddisk'. This will remove it from your explorer while keeping it on your PC.